# indent-tabs-mode is still using spaces

Tags: emacs, indentation

Below is my init.el script. It is loading because the column-indicator is visible. However editing any C file, the tab key *still* produces 4 spaces when I want only tabs (`\t`). I have never used lisp and I'm new to emacs, what's wrong?

```
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode t)
(require 'fill-column-indicator)


(defun my-c-mode-hook ()
  (setq-default c-default-style "bsd"
                c-basic-offset 4
                tab-width 4
                indent-tabs-mode t)

  (c-set-offset 'substatement-open 0)
  (fci-mode))

(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'my-c-mode-hook)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```el
(setq c-default-style "bsd")

(defun my-c-mode-hook ()
  (setq c-basic-offset 4
        tab-width 4
        indent-tabs-mode t)

  (c-set-offset 'substatement-open 0)
  (fci-mode))

(add-hook 'c-mode-hook 'my-c-mode-hook)
```

Variables have a *global* value and, potentially, a *buffer-local* value.

Furthermore certain variables will *automatically* use a buffer-local value when you set them. Such variables include `c-basic-offset`, `tab-width`, and `indent-tabs-mode` (as you can see for yourself if you describe them via <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>)

`setq-default` sets the *global* value of a variable, but by the time that `c-mode-hook` runs the buffer-local values have already been established, so setting the default value at that point isn't really what you want, as it doesn't affect the existing local values (although depending on how the mode works, doing so may cause *future* buffers to have the desired values).

`setq` sets the buffer-local value when one exists (and the global value otherwise), so this is what you want to use for most of those variables.

`c-default-style` conversely is not automatically buffer-local, so there should be no purpose in setting that with `c-mode-hook`. We can just set its (global) value once.

Comment: Thanks for the information, unfortunately, this does not work. I am at the point where the only code in the `~/.emacs.d/init.el` file is the code you have posted. Atlas, when I open a new emacs process, I open the scratch buffer, and run `M-x c-mode`. I proceed to type `main()<\n>{<\n>`. This automatically indents me with 4 spaces :(. Even if I indent manually I get 4 spaces. FYI there is no `~/.emacs` file at all.

Comment: I'd also like to add that fundamental-mode uses `\t`s just fine.

Comment: I can't replicate your issue. Can you run `emacs -Q` then paste the above code (minus the `(fci-mode)` call, as that's not standard) into the scratch buffer, and use `M-x eval-buffer` to evaluate it, and then see whether the problem occurs? If it doesn't, then there's something else in your config which was causing it. Also, what does `M-x emacs-version` report?

Comment: so I actually hopped on the emacs IRC and spoke with the elders. They where not able to replicate my problem. I used `emacs -Q tmp.c` then ran `M-x c-set-style RET bsd`. I got 8 spaces on indents, the elders (including yourself) got tabs. To make matters worse, I went on two other debian servers and installed emacs I repeated the process and got spaces on even those. 3 different machines, 3 fresh installs, all of them do not yield tabs. Version `24.5.1/lgw01-04`, `24.4.1/trouble`, `24.5.1/trouble` on my desktop, server A and server B respectfully.

Comment: How are you installing? What are `/trouble` and `/lgw01-04` ? Those aren't normal parts of the `emacs-version` output. Is it possible that you're running a non-standard build?

Comment: `/trouble` and `/lgw01-04` were the end parts of the version... not sure if they're useful or not here's the full thing: `GNU Emacs 24.4.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) of 2015-03-07 on trouble, modified by Debian`. I am installing via `apt install emacs`.

Comment: I wonder what the Debian modifications are, then. It *seems* really unlikely that they'd mess something like that up, but I don't know for sure. If you're willing to compile Emacs from source, it would be good to find out whether that makes a difference (but if so then I'd expect this to be a really common problem, and clearly it isn't).

Comment: Are you using GUI or terminal Emacs? Can you confirm whether that makes a difference?

Comment: Phils, I have good news. It was never broken in the first place. It was a me problem. I tested "if it was spaces" by using the backspace. Little did I know that backspace always converts tabs to spaces.

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out -- that explanation would never have occurred to me.